# WinRT TextBlock codebehind Canvas.Left animation

Tags: animation, storyboard, windows-runtime, textblock

I am getting error :

WinRT information: Cannot resolve TargetProperty Canvas.Left on specified object.

Getting this error on run ( build is ok ). Important part of the code:

```
var canvasAnim = new DoubleAnimation() { To = -50, Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3)) };
Storyboard.SetTarget(canvasAnim, MyWipedText);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(canvasAnim, "Canvas.Left");
```

I am attaching animation in code behind because this is done after a general swipe on a bigger control. 
Any idea how to get this property to work ? ( Opacity works fine here btw ).

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do "(Canvas.Left)" as in

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(canvasAnim, "(Canvas.Left)");
```

Note that it does not work for custom (user defined) attached dependency properties.

Comment: @FilipSkakun: The `..."(Canvas.Left)"` did the trick for me too. It seems that the parentheses are for attached properties. In my case, I eliminated the error by putting the attached properties in the parentheses in the XAML(instead of by code) and it worked like a charm. See below:

`.......Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Row)">`


Thnx Filip